# ¿Por que el Selector de atributo "[href]"en css no funciona con una etiqueta "<a>" en HTML

Tags: html, css

Estos son mis codigos de HMTL y CSS

html:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <p>Aqui hay un enlace de You tube</p>
</a>
```

y mi código "css" es el siguiente:

```
[href="https://www.youtube.com/"]{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Lo que no entiendo, es porque al querer aplicar este color de fondo al atributo, al final no pasa nada con el texto:
 "Aqui hay un enlace de You tube" y nunca se colorea de color "cyan".



Finalmente por que con los dos siguientes códigos si se rellena de color "rojo" el texto:"Enlace a Instagram", y si llego a funcionar.

html:

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es" >
Enlace a instagram
</a>
```

css:

```
[href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es"]{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Me guastaría saber porque en una no funciona y en otra si funciona y si tiene que ver algo al respecto con los elementos de tipo "BLOCK" y los elementos de tipo "inline"

Answer (score 2):

Los elementos de tipo *inline* como en este caso lo es la [tag `a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#elements) tienen algunos aspectos importantes a considerar como:

- No pueden contener elementos de tipo bloque (tag `p`)
- Aún cambiando el `display` del mismo no permitirá contener a algún elemento en bloque

Dado eso entonces conviene hacer el cambio respectivo para quedar con un cambio como el siguiente:

```html
    <style>
      p {
        background-color: crimson;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      
      [href="https://www.youtube.com/"]{
        background-color: cyan;
      }
     
    </style>
    
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
        Aqui hay un enlace de You tube
      </a>
    </p>
```

Enlace de referencia:

- [Elementos de tipo en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

*Coloqué un color de fondo al párrafo solo para su referencia visual*

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona porque tienes encerrado el texto dentro de una etiqueta de párrafo `<p></p>` y estas aplicando el color a un enlace `<a></a>` no a un párrafo.